# $_FILES empty after submit

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I'm doing a little project where the user can upload multiple images from a simple form.
When I submit the form I go in a service page where I must save the images, but this not working.
So, I tried to print `$_FILES`, and I saw that it's empty. Where is the mistake?

This is the HTML code with Bootstrap:

```
<form action="salvataggio-foto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="mb-3">
     <input class="form-control" type="file" id="images" name="images[]" multiple>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="invia">Carica</button>
</form>
```

In the service page, I have a simple `print_r($_FILES)`.

Someone can helps me? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Have you looked in [your DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools)? I don't think so, since you tried to "print" `$_FILES`. Go the the network tab where you can see all requests and responses. There you can see what is submitted. I suspect you might suffer from a redirect. To see that in the network tab you probably need to preserve (Chrome) or persist (Firefox) the log. Anyway, if you want to see what really happens the DevTools are the thing you should be using.

Comment: Please post the entire code. I tried your code and it worked fine.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] of the issue before we can help you. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your question. There's nothing wrong with your HTML form by itself, so the problem must happen at some time after you submit it. As the first comment says, start by debugging using your browser's Network tool to see what happens to the request submitted by your form. Also, it may surprise you, but some people define "empty" in different ways. To avoid ambiguity, paste into your question the actual full output you get from your `print_r($_FILES);` command, then we can see for ourselves. Thanks.